# Vulkan support on Windows Sandbox / Hyper-V Windows 11

Tags: vulkan, hyper-v, windows-sandbox

The latest Windows 11 has Vulkan support to Windows Sandbox and maybe Hyper-V so when the sandbox loads Windows, it has `vulkaninfo` available and running. and in device manager there is the actual GPU not just an emulated one.

So I tried running Vulkan application such as vkcube, and my own application.  But it is missing `VK_KHR_swapchain` extention. Is there a way to make it work? If I try vkcube I get that `VK_KHR_swapchain` is missing `vkCreateInstance`:

```
 failure vkEnumatedDeviceExtensionProperties failed to find the VK_KHR_swapchain extention
Do you have a compatible Vulkan installable client driver (ICD) installed?
```

So why does vulkaninfo show long list of available information but missing this? What is the meaning of Vulkan support if this basic part is missing?

Is there a workaround?

Tried configuring sandbox with vGpu enabled but this removed the vulkaninfo. Any suggestions?

Thanks

[link to vulkan info output on the sandbox virtual machine](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SoE4enSUjmguJtAo2yU75TTr_qFomYz4/view?usp=sharing)